# how i can open zoom window directly using python?

Tags: python

I use subprocess library but didnt work

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("C:\Users\STUDENT\AppData\Roaming\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe")
```

show this error message

```
^SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3 truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Python is interpreting `\U...` as an escape sequence.  Use a raw string instead.  `subprocess.Popen(r"...")`

Comment: like this 
```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Users\STUDENT\AppData\Roaming\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe")
```
didnt work show same msg error

Comment: I don't see how you could still be getting the same error after making that change.

Comment: You can do this through the web if you want to open a zoom link `import webbrowser as wb` then  `wb.get(using='chrome').open(zoom_link, new=2) #open zoom link in a new window`

Comment: This might help also good luck! (https://github.com/Kn0wn-Un/Auto-Zoom/blob/master/Auto.py)

Comment: there is any way else to open app on my local machine without using web for example vs code

Comment: Try this maybe `"C:\\Users\\STUDENT\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zoom\\bin\\Zoom.exe"` because the first backlash could be interpreted as a special character

Comment: also didnt work and i try to use "/"

Comment: same error though?

Comment: yes same error any way to solve this problem

Comment: I'll give your question a thumbs up so maybe someone else can figure it out good luck! Also remember to save the file before running it with new changes, might be the issue.

Comment: many thanks , sure auto save activate 

Comment: "truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape" -- that's the key. This has really nothing to do with Zoom but everything with how string literals in Python are specified. BTW: Your question lacks as [mcve]. Even though it's pretty short already, a simple `print("\Users")` should be enough, but I'm just picking nits here. Still, there are lots of questions with similar error messages, take the time to study a few of them. Also, locate the Python docs for string literals and make sure to get an overview there.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first confirming that you can run Zoom from the command line from the specified path:
`C:\Users\STUDENT\AppData\Roaming\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe`

My installation of Zoom on Windows 10 uses this path:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\zoom\bin\Zoom.exe`

If you can open Zoom from the command line (such as powershell or cmd prompt), you should be able to open with subprocess using python.

The error message associated is likely the path string, specifically `PEP 8: W605 invalid escape sequence '\'.`  If you don't escape the backlashes, python incorrectly parses the string.

Try:

```py
import subprocess
    
def main():
    subprocess.Popen("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\zoom\\bin\\Zoom.exe")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```